# Find the initial velocity's angle of a projectile knowing only the ratio between the horizontal distance traveled and max height

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, projectile

The ratio between the horizontal distance traveled and the launch height is 3 to 1. I think it is possible to find the angle given this information, but how exactly do you do it? I think it's arctan(2/3), but it's wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see how you got that answer, but if you make a sketch of the projectile's trajectory (which is a parabola) you will see why it is wrong.

You have not applied any equations which relate to projectile motion.  Find equations for the height $H$ and range $R$ as functions of launch angle $\theta$ and launch velocity $v$, then eliminate $v$ and set $R/H=3$.

Comment: ok so H=vi^2*sin(theta)/2g and R=vi^2*sin(2theta)/g. R/H then simplifies to 4cos(theta). So then final answer is cos^-1(3/4)?

Comment: If you know that arctan (2/3) is wrong, can you find out if arcos ( 3/4) is right?

Comment: No because someone told me that arctan(2/3) is wrong. I can't contact him right now so I can't find out.

Comment: Wait i messed up the math. I think it's actually arctan(4/3)

Comment: Ok I just got confirmation it's right. Thanks for the help!